# How can a handle error be thrown after Form.Shown?

Tags: c#, winforms, debugging

I have an issue where we have some horribly complex code throwing up a Win32Exception

> Error creating window handle.

Looking at the callstack I see the the bottom of the stack is from

```
MainForm_ShownEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)//I Had a type-o here...arguments were wrong
{
    someControl.Parent = contentPanel;//call starts here
}
```

The top of the stack comes from a custom event.  The event handler is in MainForm

```
anotherControl_RefreshEvent(object sender, PhysDocEventArgs e)
{
   Text = titleBarText;//win32 exception
}
```

How is this possible?  Aren't we guaranteed to have a handle created once `Form.Shown` has been called?

**Update**

Immediate window tells me `this.Handle` is 0.  where `this` is the MainForm object.

**Stack Trace** (This is 19 pages long, had to delete some)

```
    System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.CreateHandle(System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams cp)    
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateHandle() 
    System.Windows.Forms.Form.CreateHandle()    
    DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm.CreateHandle()  
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.RecreateHandleCore()   
    System.Windows.Forms.Form.RecreateHandleCore()  
    System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnTextChanged(System.EventArgs e) 
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.Text.set(string value) 
    System.Windows.Forms.Form.Text.set(string value)    
>   BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.UI.Forms.MainForm.TemplateBaseControl_RefreshEvent(object sender = {BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.UI.UserControls.TemplateBaseControl}, BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.BL.PhysDocEventArgs e = {BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.BL.PhysDocEventArgs}) Line 46    C#
    BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.UI.UserControls.TemplateBaseControl.RefreshControls() Line 323 C#
    BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.UI.UserControls.TemplateBaseControl.RunCreateControlProcess(bool destroyControls = false, bool reload = false, bool createControls = false, BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.UI.LoadingForm loading = null) Line 1020  C#
    BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.UI.UserControls.TemplateBaseControl.docNode_Resize(object sender = {BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.UI.UserControls.PDDocumentNodeControl}, System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) Line 683 C#
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnResize(System.EventArgs e)   
    System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.OnResize(System.EventArgs e)   
    BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.UI.UserControls.PDDocumentNodeControl.OnResize(System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) Line 140   C#
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnSizeChanged(System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) 
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height, int clientWidth, int clientHeight)   
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBounds() 
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmWindowPosChanged(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m = {System.Windows.Forms.Message})    
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    
    System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)  
    System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)  
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    
    System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg = 71, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam)    
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetBoundsCore(int x, int y, int width, int height, System.Windows.Forms.BoundsSpecified specified = Width) 
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height, System.Windows.Forms.BoundsSpecified specified) 
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.Width.set(int value)   
    BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.UI.UserControls.TemplateBaseControl.RefreshControls() Line 332 C#
    BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.UI.UserControls.TemplateBaseControl.RunCreateControlProcess(bool destroyControls = false, bool reload = false, bool createControls = false, BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.UI.LoadingForm loading = null) Line 1020  C#
    BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.UI.UserControls.TemplateBaseControl.docNode_Resize(object sender = {BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.UI.UserControls.PDDocumentNodeControl}, System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) Line 683 C#
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnResize(System.EventArgs e)   
    System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.OnResize(System.EventArgs e)   
    BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.UI.UserControls.PDDocumentNodeControl.OnResize(System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) Line 140   C#
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnSizeChanged(System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) 
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height, int clientWidth, int clientHeight)   
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBounds() 
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmWindowPosChanged(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m = {System.Windows.Forms.Message})    
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    
    System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)  
    System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)  
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    
    System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg = 71, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam)    
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetBoundsCore(int x, int y, int width, int height, System.Windows.Forms.BoundsSpecified specified = Width) 
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height, System.Windows.Forms.BoundsSpecified specified) 
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.Width.set(int value)   
    BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.UI.UserControls.TemplateBaseControl.RefreshControls() Line 332 C#
    BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.UI.UserControls.TemplateBaseControl.RunCreateControlProcess(bool destroyControls = false, bool reload = false, bool createControls = false, BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.UI.LoadingForm loading = null) Line 1020  C#
    BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.UI.UserControls.TemplateBaseControl.docNode_Resize(object sender = {BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.UI.UserControls.PDDocumentNodeControl}, System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) Line 683 C#
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnResize(System.EventArgs e)   
    System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.OnResize(System.EventArgs e)   
    BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.UI.UserControls.PDDocumentNodeControl.OnResize(System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) Line 140   C#
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnSizeChanged(System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) 
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height, int clientWidth, int clientHeight)   
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBounds() 
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmWindowPosChanged(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m = {System.Windows.Forms.Message})    
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    
    System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)  
    System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)  
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    
    System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg = 71, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam)    
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetBoundsCore(int x, int y, int width, int height, System.Windows.Forms.BoundsSpecified specified = Height)    
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height, System.Windows.Forms.BoundsSpecified specified) 
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.Height.set(int value)  
    BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.UI.UserControls.PDDocumentNodeControl.RefreshSize(bool setAnchorAndWidth = false) Line 109 C#
    BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.UI.UserControls.PDDocumentNodeControl.ctrl_Resize(object sender = {System.Windows.Forms.Panel}, System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) Line 442  C#
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnResize(System.EventArgs e)   
    System.Windows.Forms.Panel.OnResize(System.EventArgs eventargs) 
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnSizeChanged(System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) 
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height, int clientWidth, int clientHeight)   
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBounds() 
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmWindowPosChanged(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m = {System.Windows.Forms.Message})    
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
```

(DELETED section)

```
BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.UI.UserControls.TemplateBaseControl.RefreshControls() Line 332 C#
BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.UI.UserControls.TemplateBaseControl.RunCreateControlProcess(bool destroyControls = false, bool reload = false, bool createControls = false, BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.UI.LoadingForm loading = null) Line 1020  C#
BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.UI.UserControls.TemplateBaseControl.docNode_Resize(object sender = {BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.UI.UserControls.PDDocumentNodeControl}, System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) Line 683 C#
System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnResize(System.EventArgs e)   
System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.OnResize(System.EventArgs e)   
BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.UI.UserControls.PDDocumentNodeControl.OnResize(System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) Line 140   C#
System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnSizeChanged(System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height, int clientWidth, int clientHeight)   
System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBounds() 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmWindowPosChanged(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m = {System.Windows.Forms.Message})    
System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    
System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)  
System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    
System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)  
System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    
System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg = 71, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam)    
[Native to Managed Transition]  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetBoundsCore(int x, int y, int width, int height, System.Windows.Forms.BoundsSpecified specified = Height)    
System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height, System.Windows.Forms.BoundsSpecified specified) 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.Height.set(int value)  
BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.UI.UserControls.PDDocumentNodeControl.RefreshSize(bool setAnchorAndWidth = false) Line 109 C#
BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.UI.UserControls.PDDocumentNodeControl.ctrl_Resize(object sender = {System.Windows.Forms.Panel}, System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) Line 442  C#
System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnResize(System.EventArgs e)   
System.Windows.Forms.Panel.OnResize(System.EventArgs eventargs) 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnSizeChanged(System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height, int clientWidth, int clientHeight)   
System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBounds() 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmWindowPosChanged(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m = {System.Windows.Forms.Message})    
System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    
System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)  
System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)  
System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    
System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg = 71, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam)    
[Native to Managed Transition]  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetBoundsCore(int x, int y, int width, int height, System.Windows.Forms.BoundsSpecified specified = Height)    
System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height, System.Windows.Forms.BoundsSpecified specified) 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.Height.set(int value)  
BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.Plugins.Prompt.BL.PanelPrompt.pnlOuter_Layout(object sender = {System.Windows.Forms.Panel}, System.Windows.Forms.LayoutEventArgs e = {System.Windows.Forms.LayoutEventArgs}) Line 164  C#
System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnLayout(System.Windows.Forms.LayoutEventArgs levent = {System.Windows.Forms.LayoutEventArgs}) 
System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.OnLayout(System.Windows.Forms.LayoutEventArgs levent)    
System.Windows.Forms.Control.PerformLayout(System.Windows.Forms.LayoutEventArgs args)   
System.Windows.Forms.Control.System.Windows.Forms.Layout.IArrangedElement.PerformLayout(System.Windows.Forms.Layout.IArrangedElement affectedElement, string affectedProperty)  
System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnResize(System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs})  
System.Windows.Forms.Panel.OnResize(System.EventArgs eventargs) 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnSizeChanged(System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height, int clientWidth, int clientHeight)   
System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBounds() 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmWindowPosChanged(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m = {System.Windows.Forms.Message})    
System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    
System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)  
System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)  
System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    
System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg = 71, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam)    
[Native to Managed Transition]  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetBoundsCore(int x, int y, int width, int height, System.Windows.Forms.BoundsSpecified specified = Width) 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height, System.Windows.Forms.BoundsSpecified specified) 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.Width.set(int value)   
BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.UI.UserControls.PDDocumentNodeControl.OnResize(System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) Line 150   C#
System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnSizeChanged(System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height, int clientWidth, int clientHeight)   
System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBounds() 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmWindowPosChanged(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m = {System.Windows.Forms.Message})    
System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    
System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)  
System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    
System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)  
System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    
System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg = 71, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam)    
[Native to Managed Transition]  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetBoundsCore(int x, int y, int width, int height, System.Windows.Forms.BoundsSpecified specified = Width) 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height, System.Windows.Forms.BoundsSpecified specified) 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.Width.set(int value)   
BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.UI.UserControls.TemplateBaseControl.RefreshControls() Line 332 C#
BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.UI.UserControls.TemplateBaseControl.RunCreateControlProcess(bool destroyControls = false, bool reload = false, bool createControls = false, BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.UI.LoadingForm loading = null) Line 1020  C#
BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.UI.UserControls.TemplateBaseControl.docNode_Resize(object sender = {BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.UI.UserControls.PDDocumentNodeControl}, System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) Line 683 C#
System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnResize(System.EventArgs e)   
System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.OnResize(System.EventArgs e)   
BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.UI.UserControls.PDDocumentNodeControl.OnResize(System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) Line 140   C#
System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnSizeChanged(System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height, int clientWidth, int clientHeight)   
System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBounds() 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmWindowPosChanged(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m = {System.Windows.Forms.Message})    
System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    
System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)  
System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    
System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)  
System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    
System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg = 71, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam)    
[Native to Managed Transition]  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetBoundsCore(int x, int y, int width, int height, System.Windows.Forms.BoundsSpecified specified = Height)    
System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height, System.Windows.Forms.BoundsSpecified specified) 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.Height.set(int value)  
BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.UI.UserControls.PDDocumentNodeControl.RefreshSize(bool setAnchorAndWidth = false) Line 109 C#
BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.UI.UserControls.PDDocumentNodeControl.ctrl_Resize(object sender = {System.Windows.Forms.Panel}, System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) Line 442  C#
System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnResize(System.EventArgs e)   
System.Windows.Forms.Panel.OnResize(System.EventArgs eventargs) 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnSizeChanged(System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height, int clientWidth, int clientHeight)   
System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBounds() 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmWindowPosChanged(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m = {System.Windows.Forms.Message})    
System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    
System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)  
System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)  
System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    
System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg = 71, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam)    
[Native to Managed Transition]  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetBoundsCore(int x, int y, int width, int height, System.Windows.Forms.BoundsSpecified specified = Height)    
System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height, System.Windows.Forms.BoundsSpecified specified) 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.Height.set(int value)  
BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.Plugins.Prompt.BL.PanelPrompt.pnlOuter_Layout(object sender = {System.Windows.Forms.Panel}, System.Windows.Forms.LayoutEventArgs e = {System.Windows.Forms.LayoutEventArgs}) Line 164  C#
System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnLayout(System.Windows.Forms.LayoutEventArgs levent = {System.Windows.Forms.LayoutEventArgs}) 
System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.OnLayout(System.Windows.Forms.LayoutEventArgs levent)    
System.Windows.Forms.Control.PerformLayout(System.Windows.Forms.LayoutEventArgs args)   
System.Windows.Forms.Control.System.Windows.Forms.Layout.IArrangedElement.PerformLayout(System.Windows.Forms.Layout.IArrangedElement affectedElement, string affectedProperty)  
System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnResize(System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs})  
System.Windows.Forms.Panel.OnResize(System.EventArgs eventargs) 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnSizeChanged(System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height, int clientWidth, int clientHeight)   
System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBounds() 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmWindowPosChanged(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m = {System.Windows.Forms.Message})    
System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    
System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)  
System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)  
System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    
System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg = 71, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam)    
[Native to Managed Transition]  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetBoundsCore(int x, int y, int width, int height, System.Windows.Forms.BoundsSpecified specified = Width) 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height, System.Windows.Forms.BoundsSpecified specified) 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.Width.set(int value)   
BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.UI.UserControls.PDDocumentNodeControl.OnResize(System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) Line 150   C#
System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnSizeChanged(System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height, int clientWidth, int clientHeight)   
System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBounds() 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmWindowPosChanged(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m = {System.Windows.Forms.Message})    
System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    
System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)  
System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    
System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)  
System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    
System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg = 71, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam)    
[Native to Managed Transition]  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetBoundsCore(int x, int y, int width, int height, System.Windows.Forms.BoundsSpecified specified = Width) 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height, System.Windows.Forms.BoundsSpecified specified) 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.Width.set(int value)   
BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.UI.UserControls.TemplateBaseControl.RefreshControls() Line 332 C#
BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.UI.UserControls.TemplateBaseControl.RunCreateControlProcess(bool destroyControls = false, bool reload = false, bool createControls = false, BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.UI.LoadingForm loading = null) Line 1020  C#
BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.UI.UserControls.TemplateBaseControl.OnResize(System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) Line 1073    C#
System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnSizeChanged(System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height, int clientWidth, int clientHeight)   
System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBounds() 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmWindowPosChanged(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m = {System.Windows.Forms.Message})    
System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    
System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)  
System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    
System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)  
System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    
System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg = 71, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam)    
[Native to Managed Transition]  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
DevExpress.Utils.Win.Hook.ControlWndHook.WindowProc(System.IntPtr hWnd, int message, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam)    
[Native to Managed Transition]  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetBoundsCore(int x, int y, int width, int height, System.Windows.Forms.BoundsSpecified specified = None)  
System.Windows.Forms.Control.System.Windows.Forms.Layout.IArrangedElement.SetBounds(System.Drawing.Rectangle bounds, System.Windows.Forms.BoundsSpecified specified)    
System.Windows.Forms.Layout.DefaultLayout.xLayoutDockedControl(System.Windows.Forms.Layout.IArrangedElement element, System.Drawing.Rectangle newElementBounds, bool measureOnly, ref System.Drawing.Size preferredSize, ref System.Drawing.Rectangle remainingBounds)  
System.Windows.Forms.Layout.DefaultLayout.LayoutDockedControls(System.Windows.Forms.Layout.IArrangedElement container, bool measureOnly = false)    
System.Windows.Forms.Layout.DefaultLayout.xLayout(System.Windows.Forms.Layout.IArrangedElement container = {System.Windows.Forms.Panel}, bool measureOnly = false, out System.Drawing.Size preferredSize = {Width = -7103 Height = -7105})  
System.Windows.Forms.Layout.DefaultLayout.LayoutCore(System.Windows.Forms.Layout.IArrangedElement container, System.Windows.Forms.LayoutEventArgs args) 
System.Windows.Forms.Layout.LayoutEngine.Layout(object container, System.Windows.Forms.LayoutEventArgs layoutEventArgs) 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnLayout(System.Windows.Forms.LayoutEventArgs levent)  
System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.OnLayout(System.Windows.Forms.LayoutEventArgs levent)    
System.Windows.Forms.Control.PerformLayout(System.Windows.Forms.LayoutEventArgs args)   
System.Windows.Forms.Control.System.Windows.Forms.Layout.IArrangedElement.PerformLayout(System.Windows.Forms.Layout.IArrangedElement affectedElement, string affectedProperty)  
System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection.Add(System.Windows.Forms.Control value = {BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.UI.UserControls.TemplateBaseControl}) 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.ParentInternal.set(System.Windows.Forms.Control value) 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.Parent.set(System.Windows.Forms.Control value) 
BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.UI.Forms.MainForm.MainForm_Shown(object sender = {BHCS.ECC.PhysDoc.UI.Forms.MainForm}, System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) Line 88    C#
System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnShown(System.EventArgs e)   
System.Windows.Forms.Form.CallShownEvent()  
System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(System.Windows.Forms.Control.ThreadMethodEntry tme)  
System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(object obj)  
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)    
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)    
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state)  
System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(System.Windows.Forms.Control.ThreadMethodEntry tme)    
System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks() 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    
System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)  
System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)   
System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)   
DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg)   
System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)  
System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    
System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg = 49734, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam) 
[Appdomain Transition]  
[Native to Managed Transition]  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame = {System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame}) Line 2281    Unknown
System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame) Line 368  Unknown
System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run() Line 327  Unknown
System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(object ignore) Line 2745   C#
System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window window) Line 1841  C#
System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window window) Line 261   C#
Eclipsys.Infrastructure.UIShell.App.Main()
```

Comment: Maybe it the handle of a control on the form that is having the problem and not the handle of the form itself.

Comment: @SteveWellens - titleBarText is a string object.  Text is a property of `MainForm.Text`.  I believe it's not possible since no control is involved in this line of code.

Comment: You can check the handle, what is the value of this.Handle?  Are there many controls on the form?  You could try temporarily deleting them all and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: @StevenWellens - this.Handle value = 0.  There are a ton of controls on the window.  The program is essentially a control creator.  Imagine a busted a** sharepoint.  It's also possible that MainForm is a new object, but I have not found any evidence of such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an exception that has an easy diagnostic and a very common cause.  Start diagnosing with Task Manager, Processes tab.  View + Select columns, tick USER Objects.  While you are at it, tick GDI Objects and Handles as well.  Run the program and observe the USER Objects value of the process while you use the program's features.

If the value you see is steadily climbing then your program is leaking window handles.  Once the value reaches 10000 then Windows stops giving it more windows, the process has consumed its quota.  The exception raised by that is "Error creating window handle".

The cause is a very common programming mistake in Winforms.  It happens when you remove controls from their parent by using Controls.Remove/At() or Controls.Clear() but forget to call the Dispose() method on those removed controls.  Which will make them live forever, kept alive by their window handle.

Comment: +1 I'll dig into this.  From the errors we've had in the past and such this sounds *very* promising!

Comment: Not quite 10,000 at the point the exception is thrown.  Handles/User Objects/GDI at 1278/1376/799 respectively.

Comment: Post the full stack trace of the exception.  Be sure to enable unmanaged debugging and enable the Microsoft Symbols Server so we can also see the native stack frames.

Comment: Drag your machine to a 4th floor window.  Open the window and shove it out.  Opening the window first is optional.

Comment: Gonna have to continue hacking away at this terrible architecture.  You've given me a good idea of what kinds of issues to look for and that's just the best that we can do with this mess.